# SQL Report Builder - How can we generate multiple result set in report builder?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we generate a report that consists of multiple tables?
I have a stored procedure that will generate multiple result set, i want to generate a report with all that tables in to an excel. I tried but i was only able to get one table at a time.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple tables in sql report builder? please let me know ASAP.

Comment: Please let me know why this was down voted. So that i will know whats wrong in asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Procedures that return multiple result sets do not play nice with SSRS.   You need to build a result set in report builder for each result set that you need to represent in the report.

You can't use a single SSRS result set to call a proc that returns multiple result sets and access it as a collection of result sets the way you can in .net.

Once you have your multiple result sets created, you can create multiple tablix on your report, and designate in each one which result set it uses for its data.

Comment: Thanks for the response.How can you create multiple tablix on the report? Do you mean after generating it to excel from SQL Report builder and then merge it manually? Is that it ? Please let me know.

Comment: No I mean simply drag-and-drop more than one tablix onto the report.  Like, one on the top half, and one on the bottom.   Or one on the left and one on the right.   Just like having two or more html Tables on a web page.  Or two DataGrids on a .net page/form.

Comment: I see. Is there any links that you can provide me with an example.

Comment: Nothing I have handy.  It's a very basic operation, so any beginning tutorial on SSRS should have a section on adding a Tablix.

Comment: Thankyou im a rookie so can't upvote ur answer at the moment. I don't know why i got down voted for the question i asked. Have you got any idea why?

Comment: No idea, sorry.  I don't see any close votes on your question.  It's a shame the downvoters didn't comment.